# Make notification alerts persist until links are clicked?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

Can a setting be made that makes notification alerts (the red number in the top left) persist, only be reduced when each link is clicked? This would be similar to how an e-mail inbox counts unread e-mails until they are read. Currently the entire alert is dismissed upon opening the notifications list, which can easily make one lose track of which notifications have or have not been addressed.

Comment: On the other side of things, not everyone wants to have to click on *every single* thing in order to dismiss it, especially if you've gathered quite a large number of notifications since you last checked your inbox.

Comment: And especially when you have answering speeds comparable to Jon Skeet. So many comments; from even old replies

Comment: "Can a setting be made…" Not "Can it be changed for all..."

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: SE is known for *rarely ever* making "settings." They complicate the system and the UX. It's always been all or none.